# What’s wrong with “I jump into a pool”

Tags: grammar, tenses

My son’s teacher gave him homework where he needed to make a sentence with ‘jump’. 
So he wrote “I jump into a pool”. But he was marked wrong. 
The teacher has explained saying that it has to be “I jumped into a pool.”

I was just wondering if it really is wrong to say, “I jump into the pool.’ If yes then why is it wrong.

Comment: It's really hard to say with things like this. We don't know what the teacher's expectations are or the context (is this ESL? or first grade? or story telling? or what). Yes, all by itself 'I jump into the pool' is formally correct, but it is not very natural. 'I jump into the pool whenever I am hot' is much more natural.

Comment: I'm not sure enough to make this an answer, but I suspect it's because "_I jump into a pool._" isn't really a standalone sentence (whereas "_I jumped into a pool._" can be). Mitch has just beaten me to an example where it can be part of a longer sentence.

Comment: if allowed one could have drawn a stick figure plunging into water!  the sentence is fine imho.

Comment: If there is no further guidance, I don't see how the perfectly grammatical 'I jump into a pool' can be marked wrong. It would rarely be used in writing or conversation, but could be a whimsical caption on a photograph, say.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Agreed. It's unfair to mark this as wrong if the instruction was simply: _Make a sentence with 'jump'_. Maybe the boy should tell his teacher he was using the _historical present_: _I run out of the house. I jump into the pool, etc._ But _I jump into *a* pool_ sounds less likely. The OP switches from indefinite to definite article, so it's not clear what the boy actually wrote.

Comment: "I jump*ed* into a pool" doesn't actually use the word *jump*.

Answer (score 2):

Curiously enough, the [present tense simple](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/) does not describe actions that are happening right now, but

- **habitual/repeated action**

> My children watch too much television.
>
> When we visit Ravenna, we always stay at the Byron Centrale.

- **general truths, conditions, opinions**

> At sea level, water boils at 100°C.
>
> Seattle has very cloudy weather.
>
> I prefer fries with mayo, not ketchup.

- **instructions, directions**

> First, we take I35 to Dallas, then turn onto I20 to Shreveport.
>
> To make a Victoria sponge, one first separates the eggs.

- **future planned event with adverb of time, subordinate clauses of time**

> He flies to Rome next Tuesday.
>
> You'll see her before she leaves.
>
> We'll surprise her with the new car when she arrives

Your son's sentence with *jump* would make perfect sense if temporally anchored like any of these examples.

> If I want to cool off in a hurry, I jump in a pool. (habitual, repeated action)
>
> What do you do to cool off in a hurry? I jump in a pool.
>
> It's going to feel so refreshing when I jump in the pool. (adverbial subordinate clause)

Otherwise, the present tense sounds non-idiomatic and your son's teacher suggested the past tense simple instead.